# Is there any way to append the result of a command after the end of other?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

The same way most SQL db systems provide  a `UNION` statement to combine the results of two selects, I would like to generate an output stream from two commands outputs in bash.

One example (this is just an example, don't take it as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) : I want to look for the word `"name"` within `cpp` files contained in two different folders:

```
grep name $(find /home/whoever/ -name "*.cpp")
grep name $(find /mnt/hd -name "*.cpp")
```

This works in two steps but I'd like to do in just one, something like:

```
grep name { $(find /mnt/hd -name "*.cpp") UNION $(find /mnt/hd -name "*.cpp") }
```

**EDIT**

As some answers suggest, the example can be easily approached in a more straightforward way but that is just an example, I'd like to know whether there is a way to create an output stream combining (one after another is OK) two other streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `find` run in 2 directories:

```
find /home/whoever/ /mnt/hd -name "*.cpp" -exec grep "name" '{}' \; -print
```

**To answer your comment on adding 2 commands then taking their combined output:**

```
{ find /mnt/hd -name "*.cpp"; find /mnt/hd -name "*.cpp"; } | grep "name"
```

Comment: +1 Because this solve the concrete example but I can't accept the answer because that just works for this example, the question I have is how can I generically combine two whatsoever commands outputs (if that is even possible)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `cat` plus [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).  E.g.,

```
cat                                                    \
    <(grep name $(find /home/whoever/ -name "*.cpp"))  \
    <(grep name $(find /mnt/hd -name "*.cpp"))
```

This works with any number of commands.  Indeed, the general form is

```
cat <(list_1) <(list_2) ... <(list_n)
```

where each `list_i` is a valid command expression.

Be aware, however, that process substitution is a Bash extension; other shells (e.g., strictly POSIX-compliant shells) might not support it.

Comment: +1 Good solution, not the accepted one since anubhava's seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Mine is far more general, though.

Comment: @RobertoReale I may be missing something, in what way?

Comment: Just fyi, there is really no way what I suggested is not generic and this is more generic. This in fact is less efficient because of more number of processes involved. Just count, suggested answer here has `2 find + 2 grep + 1 cat` and what I suggested has `2 find + 1 grep`.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo My solution allows for any number of commands of any kind...  E.g., `diff <(sort first_file) <(sort second_file)`...

Comment: @RobertoReale Yes,your solution works for many commands but as anubhava said it increase load of no of command execution. why you run 2 times `grep` and `find` commands if one command already done it?.

Comment: @RobertoReale Doesn't `cat <(list_1) <(list_2) ... <(list_n)` provide the same result than `{list_1; list_2; ...; list_n} | cat`?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo: Exactly what I was also going to write. It seems Roberto has a bit of misunderstanding about `{ cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; ...; cmdN; }` which can be used to execute **any number of commands** in a group and then use their combined output outside the group for piping or whatever.

Comment: @anubhava **No.**  Do you think that `{ sort file1; sort file2 ; } | diff` is equivalent to `diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`??

Comment: Roberto, your example command is wrong since `diff` is not run in pipe like that. Just try it out first.

Comment: Of course your solution `{ sort file1; sort file2 ; } | diff` **does not work**.  On the other hand, `diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` **does work** very well.  It is, indeed, a more general (and different) construct.

Comment: `diff` is totally absurd example here since `diff` is **run on 2 input files/streams** not on a combined (union) output as asked by OP. I think you need to read the question again.

Comment: `diff` is a counterexample which proves that your solution is less general than mine is.  However, you seem to be a little too troubled by the fact that someone's answer (or knownledge, for that matter) may be better than yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell diff to search in multiple directories :

```
find dir1 dir2 ... dirn -name "*.cpp"
```

**Update**

to combine commands use curly braces "Braces are also used to execute a sequence of commands in the current shell context"

example

```
{ command1 ; command2 ; ....; command n} >logfile

#command1 and command 2 can be the same command
{ echo "Hello" ; echo "World" ;} > logfile
#or a combination of different commands
{ date; top -b -n1 | head ; } >logfile
```

Comment: +1 Because this solve the concrete example but I can't accept the answer because that just works for this example, the question I have is how can I generically combine two whatsoever commands outputs (if that is even possible)

Comment: why giving different example instead giving exact one?

Comment: Just to show that you can use whatsoever commands :) i could simply do {echo "who" ; echo "lets" ; echo "the dog" ; echo "out" ;} > logfile

Comment: @bachN This is understandable you but important is what OP wants. See OP's comment to your answer.

Comment: @i think  Pablo Francisco Pérez Hidalgo understood very well my answer, but yes i get your point, i'll update my answer ;)

Comment: @bachN Yes I did, indeed I think using different commands stress the fact that it can work for different examples.